# dagger2 and android: load module which injects viewmodel on a map

Tags: android, dagger-2

I've started using Dagger2, so there's still a lot to learn. I'm wondering if someone could point me on the right direction.

So, I've created a module for registering the view models used by my activities. It looks like this:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainActivityViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun bindMainActivityViewModel(viewModel: MainActivityViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ShowDetailsViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindShowDetaislViewModel(viewModel: ShowDetailsViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

`ViewModelKey` is a simple helper annotation class which looks like this:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey (val value: KClass<out ViewModel>) {
}
```

The `ViewModelModule` is loaded by my main app component (used for creating the app):

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules=[
            AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
            AppModule::class,
            DatabaseModule::class,
            NewsServiceModule::class,
            JobBindingModule::class,
            ViewModelModule::class,
            PreferencesModule::class,
            ActivityBindingModule::class
        ]
)
interface AppComponent: AndroidInjector<MyApp> {
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder: AndroidInjector.Builder<MyApp>()
}
```

And here's the code for the `ActivityBindingModule`, responsible for setting up the subcomponents (in this case, activities used by my app):

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector()
    internal abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    internal abstract fun showDetailsActivity(): ShowDetailsActivity
}
```

Internally, each activity is instantiating the view model with code that looks like this (called from within the `onCreate` method):

```
//view model code
_viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)[ShowDetailsViewModel::class.java]
```

And, as you'd expect, `viewModelFactory` is injected as field:

```
@Inject lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
```

Both view models have external dependencies which are set up on the other modules referenced by the top app component.

And, for the sake of completeness, here's the code for my view model factory:

```
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T
        = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
```

This code works, but it seems like it can be improved. After reading the docs, I'm under the impression that I could refactor my `ViewModeModule` so that it will simply instantiate my `ViewModelFactory` and move each of the view model declarations into separate module (so that each of them can be injected only in the "correct" activity).

In order to test this, I've started by moving the `ShowDetailsViewModel` into a new module which has only one entry:

```
@Module
internal abstract class DetailsModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ShowDetailsViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindShowDetaislViewModel(viewModel: ShowDetailsViewModel): ViewModel

}
```

After that, the ViewModelModule looks like this:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainActivityViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun bindMainActivityViewModel(viewModel: MainActivityViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

And I've updated the `ActivityBindingModule` so that in looks like this:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector()
    internal abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [DetailsModule::class])
    internal abstract fun showDetailsActivity(): ShowDetailsActivity
}
```

Notice that now I'm passing the `DetailsModule` (which instantiates the `ShowDetailsViewModel`) to the `ContributeAndroidInjector` annotation which is applied to the `showDetailsActivity` method because that view model is only used by that activity.

Now, I'm surely missing something because after doing this, I'm always getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewModelProviders.of(th…ilsViewModel::class.java] must not be null
```

If I debug the app, I can see that moving the ShowDetailsViewModel into its own model does not register it on the map used by the factory (ie, the map has only one entry, which corresponds to the `MainActivityViewModel` that is registered in the ViewModelModule.

I thought that moving each view model the declaration into each a module used by a subcomponent should still allow it to be registered in a map injected by a module which is registered with the top component. Am I wrong? What is it that  I'm missing to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: I would guess the problem lies with `ViewModelFactory` being `@Singleton` and that it won't get any of the bindings you add in your subcomponents. Try removing the scope or making it `@ActivityScoped` as well

Comment: Hello David. But since the activity is a subcomponent, shouldn't it have access to the parents graph? btw, maybe I'm missing something related with the way imtomap works...

Comment: I did not test this, it's a guess. The Activity (activiteScoped) has access to the factory (singleton), but the factory (singleton) would not have access to use or create the viewmodel (activityScoped). So moving the factory to activityScoped would give it access to create the viewmodel

Comment: Hello again David. Doing that solves the problem, but not in the way I was trying to do it. I was trying to create a global map, where all the view models register themselves. I'm guessing that to do this, I would need to add a provides method that returns a single map (I'll give it a try later). However, your solution does work, though it means the map will only have the required view models. Would you mind putting an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Hey, glad it worked, can do! With Dagger higher scopes can never access lower scopes, its only one way (Directed Acyclic Graph), so you need to either move your ViewModel declarations to singleton as well or the Factory down to the activity scope. Any other solution would require you to dynamically modify the factory, but it won't work with Dagger alone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies with `ViewModelFactory` being `@Singleton` and that it won't get any of the bindings you add in your subcomponents. Remove the scope from your factory or make it `@ActivityScoped` (the same scope as the ViewModel for the Activity)

The Activity (`@ActivityScoped`) has access to the factory (`@Singleton`), but the factory (`@Singleton`) does not have access to use or create the ViewModel from a lower scope (`@ActivityScoped`). So moving the factory to the same scope (`@ActivityScoped`) would give it access to create the viewmodel in question.