# Dagger2, adding a binding for ViewModelProvider.Factory in a dependant component

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

#### The Problem

When attempting to add a `ViewModel` bind into the multibinding for an inherited `ViewModelFactory` (created with no scope) within a lower scope (`@FragmentScope`), I keep running into this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown model class com.example.app.MyFragmentVM

#### What I've read or tried

(note: the below is not by any means an exhaustive list, but are two good examples of resources and the kinds of advice I've perused)

- [1] [dagger2 and android: load module which injects viewmodel on a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52348783/dagger2-and-android-load-module-which-injects-viewmodel-on-a-map) (and other variants / similar Q and As)
- [2] https://medium.com/tompee/dagger-2-scopes-and-subcomponents-d54d58511781

I'm relatively new to working with Dagger so I had to do a lot of Googling to try and understand what has been going on, but I've reached a point where, to my understanding, something should be working(?)...

From sources similar to [1], I removed the `@Singleton` scope on `ViewModelFactory`, but I still get the aforementioned crash saying there is no model class found in the mapping.

From sources similar to [2] I tried to reinforce my understanding of how dependencies worked and how items are exposed to dependant components. I know and understand how `ViewModelProvider.Factory` is available to my `MyFragmentComponent` and it's related Modules.

However I do not understand why the `@Binds @IntoMap` isn't working for the `MyFragmentVM`.

#### The Code

Let me first go through the setup of the stuff that already exists in the application -- almost none of it was scoped for specific cases

```kotlin
// AppComponent
@Component(modules=[AppModule::class, ViewModelModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    fun viewModelFactory(): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
    // ... and other injections
}

// AppModule
@Module
class AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesSomething(): Something

    // a bunch of other providers for the various injection sites, all @Singleton scoped
}

// ViewModelModule
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindsViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainActivityVM::class)
    abstract fun bindsMainActivityVM(vm: MainActivityVM): ViewModel
}

// VMFactory
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")

        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

And the following is how I am trying to add and utilize my @FragmentScope:

```kotlin
// MyFragmentComponent
@FragmentScope
@Component(
    dependencies = [AppComponent::class],
    modules = [MyFragmentModule::class, MyFragmentVMModule::class]
)
interface MyFragmentComponent {
    fun inject(fragment: MyFragment)
}

// MyFragmentModule
@Module
class MyFragmentModule {
    @Provides
    @FragmentScope
    fun providesVMDependency(): VMDependency {
        // ...
    }
}

// MyFragmentVMModule
@Module
abstract class MyFragmentVMModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MyFragmentVM::class)
    abstract fun bindsMyFragmentVM(vm: MyFragmentVM): ViewModel
}

// MyFragment
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    @set:Inject
    internal lateinit var vmFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private lateinit var viewModel: MyFragmentVM

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        DaggerMyFragmentComponent.builder()
            .appComponent(MyApplication.instance.component)
            .build()
            .inject(this)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, vmFactory).get(MyFragmentVM::class.java)
    }
}
```

What's interesting here to note is that `MyFragmentModule` itself does NOT end up providing any unique injections for `MyFragment` (those all come from AppComponent as it is right now). It DOES however, provide unique injections for the `ViewModel` that `MyFragment` uses.

Comment: `@Injects constructor(` should be `@Inject constructor(` probably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of this problem is the difference between **subcomponents** and **component dependencies**.

#### Subcomponents

When working with subcomponents, the parent component knows everything about its subcomponents.  As such, when a subcomponent requests a multibinding, the parent component can combine its contributions with those of the subcomponent.  This even works transitively: if the subcomponent requests an unscoped `ViewModelProvider.Factory`, the injected map will include bindings from the subcomponent.  (The same is true of a `@Reusable` binding, but not a `@Singleton`.)

If you change your components with dependencies into subcomponents, everything will just work.  However, this might not fit your desired architecture.  In particular, this is impossible if `MyFragmentComponent` is in an Instant App module.

#### Component dependencies

When working with component dependencies, the main component merely exposes objects through provision methods, and **it does not know about any components that might depend on it**.  This time, when asked for a `ViewModelProvider.Factory`, the main component does not have access to any `@ViewModelKey` bindings except its own, and so the `Factory` it returns will not include the `MyFragmentVM` binding.

If `MyFragmentComponent` does not require any `ViewModel` bindings from `AppComponent`, you can extract `bindsViewModelFactory` into its own module and include it in both components.  That way, both components can create their own `Factory` independently.

If you do need some `ViewModel` bindings from `AppComponent`, hopefully you can add those binding modules to `MyFragmentComponent` as well.  If not, you would have to expose the map in `AppComponent`, and then somehow combine those entries with your new bindings.  Dagger does not provide a good way to do this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your explanation! This makes a bunch of sense to me. When you say under component dependencies that both components can create their own Factory independently, do you mean by just including the abstracted VMFactoryModule, or do they need to do something else? I don't see how to scope the factories without using a provider or putting a scope in the abstracted bind method for ViewModelProvider.Factory, which would affect its usage everywhere

Comment: @Mephoros I may have spoken a bit too soon on that.  Scoping the factory would require two separate copies of the abstracted VMFactoryModule, which is kind of pointless.  Just leave it unscoped, or make it `@Reusable` if you want to avoid recreating it every time.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense to me. This leads to another problem now where when trying to build with the `@Reusable` VMFactoryModule included in my scoped dependant component, I receive this message: `MyFragmentComponent scoped with @FragmentScope may not reference bindings with different scopes` -- and it does not reference any specific bindings... it only occurs when I include `VMFactoryModule` in my modules list for `MyFragmentComponent` (which is necessary, otherwise ViewModelProvider.Factory has no provider)

Comment: "it does not reference any specific bindings" is better said as "the error does not call out any specific bindings"

Comment: @Mephoros I am unable to reproduce that on my end.  Double check that your `VMFactoryModule` doesn't include any `@Singleton` bindings that would be pulled in somehow.

Comment: Please see this gist for the setup that leads to that error: https://gist.github.com/prateem/7af70cf11215efbfd4c2bd3e6c1ba345

Comment: Everything in that gist looks fine.  Perhaps `FragmentViewModel` is pulling something in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210307/discussion-between-mephoros-and-nitrodon).